# How to use grep for collecting URL links?

Tags: linux, command-line, grep, cat

Let's say I have a file named **plaintext.txt** which have *2 lines* and a content of

```
you can be social online by logging in to http://www.facebook.com and http://plus.google.com
alternatively, you can also create an account in http://www.twitter.com
```

I know that I can display the whole contents of the file by issuing a **cat** statement in the command-line like

```sh
cat plaintext.txt
```

I wanted to collect all of the URL links from the plaintext such that I can display

```
http://www.facebook.com
http://plus.google.com
http://www.twitter.com
```

I presume the command line statement for this one would be something like

```sh
cat plaintext.txt | grep something
```

but I don't exactly know how.

**How is it possible to use grep for collecting URL links?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed 's/\s/\n/g' plaintext.txt | grep http:
```

where `plaintext.txt` is the file containing your two lines.

Comment: what does `sed 's/\s/\n/g'` mean?

Comment: Search for whitespaces and replace with newline

Comment: `\s` is whitespace and `\n` is newline.  Effectively, we are separating all words on their own line and then, looking for `http:` using `grep`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do with `grep` `-o` option.

```
$ cat file
you can be social online by logging in to http://www.facebook.com and http://plus.google.com
alternatively, you can also create an account in http://www.twitter.com
```

```
$ grep -o "http[^ ]*" file
http://www.facebook.com
http://plus.google.com
http://www.twitter.com
```

From the `man page`:

```
-o, --only-matching
              Show only the part of a matching line that matches PATTERN.
```